# How to clear cells in a column that have zero values

Tags: excel, null, excel-formula, zero

I'm hoping to use the replace tool or something similarly easy where I clear cells in a column that have a value of zero.

I know I could delete the cells using the filter tool, but is there a way to just clear cells with a zero value?

Or, in the 'else' clause of an 'if' statement is there a way to return a blank cell?

This would also give the result I want.

Comment: couldn't you just do a "find and replace" finding 0 and replacing with a blank value?  Don't think you can get much quicker than that!

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I tried putting 0 in the 'Find What' box and nothing in the Replace with box (and I also tried spaces). Neither clear my zeros.

Comment: are the 0s a result of formula?

Comment: =IF(J2=38,IF(K2<>0,K2,),"")   I need the nested if statement because I have zeros in my K column due to the same problem.

Comment: @pnuts Wow, thanks that works better. I can skip a step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using a helper column to replace, and paste over, I would suggest selecting your range, and then a simple find/replace for `0` with  (nothing in the "replace" box).

Edit: Do you want to remove them, or just hide them? You can also hide all `0` returns by choosing a custom cell format, and using `0;-0;;`.

Comment: Can anyone verify that this suggestion works? It doesn't for me oddly enough. My replace tool said no 0 values are found even though the column is loaded with them.

Comment: K, figured it out, none of these suggestions work if the cell value is a return from a formula. Just have to copy/paste the formula returns to another column as values. Thanks all.

Comment: @AF2k15 - Are you trying to literally remove the 0s or just hide them from view?  See my edit if it's the latter case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
=if(something, value_if_true,"")
```

or do a find (0) and replace (by blank), checking the whole cell option checkbox, assuming your cells are values and not formulas.

Comment: Tried that, since neither suggestion worked, but both suggestions seem like they should work, I wonder what trickery excel is playing.